# Visual Basic Removing a control that was added in code

Tags: visual-studio, vba, controls, basic

In one of my functions picture boxes are created and added to the form, that all works fine. Just, I want to be able to remove specific ones later on in a different function. I tried using Me.Controls.Remove(Control_Name) however this just gives a bunch of errors because the controls don't exist yet and won't build to run.

Is there any way to get around this and be able to remove the controls?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're referring to dynamic controls like this:

```
Me.Controls.Remove(Control_Name)
```

Where `Control_Name` is the name of the control that doesn't yet exist. Indeed, with `Option Explicit` specified, that *should* give you a compile error about `Control_Name` not being a declared identifier.

Think of controls as public fields (which ...they *are*) - if the control doesn't exist at design-time, then there's no field for it at compile-time, so referring to e.g. `Control_Name.Text` would be illegal.

Try using a string literal instead:

```
Me.Controls.Remove("Control_Name")
```

If possible, use a constant instead of sprinkling string literals all over your code though:

```
Const DYNAMIC_PICTUREBOX_NAME As String = "DynamicPictureBox"
```

This way you can rename all dynamic controls in one place, and then you can easily add a numeric suffix to iterate all your dynamically created picture boxes:

```
For i = 1 to 10
    Me.Controls.Remove(DYNAMIC_PICTUREBOX_NAME & i)
Next
```

Comment: I tried using strings as you suggested and now instead of the error because it doesn't exist I just get the error: `Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.` which still prevents a successful build